# node.js - retrieve table name using regex from insert statement if table name exists in SQL string

Tags: node.js, regex

I have an input string in node.js with uncertain format. this input string is an Insert SQL Query. can anybody suggest a fast and high performance piece of code to store `my_table_name` in variable?

```
INseRT   IntO my_table_Name (CustomerName) VALUES ('Cardinal');
    INseRT into  my_Table_name (CustomerName) VALUES ('Cardinal');
   INsert   into  my_table_name    (CustomerName) VALUES ('Cardinal');
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple regex to find the table name, for example:

```
const query1 = "INseRT   IntO my_table_Name (CustomerName) VALUES ('Cardinal');"
const query2 = "    INseRT into  my_Table_name (CustomerName) VALUES ('Cardinal');"
const query3 = "   INsert   into  my_table_name    (CustomerName) VALUES ('Cardinal');"

const queries = [query1, query2, query3];

pattern = /insert\s+into\s+(.*?)\s/i;

for (const query of queries) {
  const matches = query.match(pattern);
  if (matches) {
    const tableName = matches[1]
    console.log(tableName)
  }
}

>>> my_table_Name
>>> my_table_Name
>>> my_table_Name
```